# kotlin coroutines with android client side interaction

Tags: android-fragments, kotlinx.coroutines

Lets say I have one fragment that opens another fragment and waits for answer from that fragment.

Is it possible with kotlin coroutines to make the code look synchronous?

meaning something like this?

```
result = await openFragment()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With kotlin 1.3 coroutine you can do this:

```
val myFragment = async { //Your asynchronous task here }
```

This will return a Deferred object, as the official documentation describes, "a light-weight non-blocking future that represents a promise to provide a result later". When you want to get the result of this task, do this:

```
val result = myFragment.await()
```

Or, you can make use of Async-style functions to initiate your task outside a coroutine. Just define a function like this:

```
fun openFragment() = GlobalScope.async {
    //Your asynchronous task here
}
```

Then you can do this outside a coroutine:

```
val myFragment = openFragment()
```

Then you can get the result of the task the same way as above through the await function. This line still has to be put inside a coroutine.

```
val result = myFragment.await()
```